# Zend framework; Getting controller to use different viewer

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the Zend Framework.

I have a controller named 'UserController' that has a public function displayAction().

I would like to know how I can get that action method to use a different viewer than the default display.phtml.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->render('actionName');
```

or, alternatively, you can call a view script directly by calling

```
$this->renderScript('path/to/viewscript.phtml');
```

For more information, you can take a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html, specifically the parts about the `render()` and `renderScript()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, I've been getting errors with the method described above (using ZF 1.11.11). I've had success with this:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('action');
```